# Issues with require.js and sourcemaps when compiling typescript with grunt-ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs, requirejs, grunt-ts

When using `grunt-ts` and specifying and out file my app runs as expected, but since that option has no support for fast compilation, i tried using a regular compilation where all my `.ts` files live on the `dist` folder

There are two issues, first, it will fail to load any imported file, since it will try to look for it without extension. As a quick fix i edited the `load` fn on the require.js file and all my dependencies load correctly, but then the sourcemaps stopped working, all i get is a blank file on the chrome inspector (and of course i don't want to rely on a dirty hack) .

Please note that i'm not very familiar with requirejs so I'm not quite sure if this is a misconfiguration on my side, a bug, or something that is missing.

My grunt config, related to ts

```
ts: {
      options: {
        module: 'amd',
        target: 'es5',
        experimentalDecorators: true
      },
      dev: {
        src: ['client-app/**/*.ts'],
        outDir: "dist",
        watch: '.'
      }
    },
```

My `bootstrap.js` which is just the entry point and require.js config file

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: '.',
  waitSeconds: 20
});

requirejs(['/init'], function(module) {
  module.main()
});
```

A simplified version of the compiled `init` file

```
define(["require", "exports", './section-manager.view'], function (require, exports, section_manager_view_1,) {
    "use strict";
    function main() {
        ///
    }
    exports.main = main;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=init.js.map
```

And the html

```
<script src="/js/lib/require.js" data-main="/bootstrap"></script>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Edit:

Using System.js or @Luis answer solves the loading issue.
The sourcemap issue is solved by using `sourceRoot` or

```
inlineSourceMap: true,
inlineSources: true
```

To the ts options

Comment: You may want to try out something that works with commonjs modules, it would make it easier. Try Browserify, JSPM, or Webpack. They all have TS plugins.

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: @elclanrs Tried browserify at first, but i was getting lots of errors, since I'm using the new import syntax and not the node syntax

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing the error basically is that it doesn't load the file, it throws a `require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "/init"` and if i check on the network tab, its not adding the .js, by adding the extension on require.js via the hack i said before, it works, but then it messes up with the source maps

Comment: Wht are you using requirejs when you specified amd code generation for typescript compiler. I don't see a need to use requirejs.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing Well requierejs is an implementation of the amd pattern, or what do you mean?, please expand on that thought

Comment: @Zagen, `AMD` is used for async module loading on web, `commonjs` on node side. Typescript allows to define modules using es6-imports syntax and the typescript compiler can emit `amd` or `commonjs` style modular code. Requirejs was existent before typescript came into existence and was quite common on web. If you are using typescript, I do not see a need for requirejs. Code will just be scattered with `import`/`export` and `define`/`require` which to me is too much to deal with.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing you mean, using es6 syntax for modules? I'm targeting old browsers too, and if you are referring to using commonjs instead of amd, i tried that first with browserify and got another set of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an absolute module name. If you do use an absolute name, RequireJS assumes that you do not want any alteration when it generates a path from the module name and will **not** add the `.js` extension. You should use a relative path, or you could do this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/'
});

requirejs(['init'], function(module) {
  module.main()
});
```

By doing this, RequireJS will automatically add the `.js` extension.

Comment: I've read something about that too, but the thing is (which maybe i should have said) is that it was the first thing i tried, but if i do that, then the init.js doesn't even load. But let check again to confirm

Comment: Ok, i just checked, and it doesn't work, but if i append `requirejs.config({baseUrl: '/'});` before that line so that i avoid using `/` on the first initialization, it works. But the source maps aren't working, i've just tried with System.js and i get the same result, it works but sourcemaps don't seem to be loading, any ideas on that?

Comment: Yeah, you have to use a `baseUrl` and a module path that are going to work together. What do you do to trigger the loading of the sourcemaps? What network request do you see being done for loading the sourcemaps when you trigger their loading? Is the network request successful? Is it loading an actual sourcemap? You should edit your question with this information.

Comment: Thanks, i realized how to solve the sourceMap issue, using inline sourcemaps or defining "sourceRoot", please add the line of code that sets the baseUrl on your code and i'll mark it as the accepted answer for future reference for other users